# How is ReadKey able to read a key after KeyAvailable is set to true?

Tags: c#

I understand that the following pattern works to capture a keypress

```
while(true)
{
    if(Console.KeyAvailable)
       var readKey = Console.ReadKey();
}
```

What I dont understand however, is if ReadKey is a blocking operation and waits for user input, then how can it be run AFTER the computer knows a key has been pressed? Could someone explain what is going on under the hood here?

Comment: Think of the keyboard as a buffered stream. The key press puts data into this stream buffer. The OS notices there is a key available to be read, and sets the flag. Reading the key will read the next key out of the buffer.

Comment: Is this a race condition in a way? Since I have to read the key before the buffer is flushed to the console, if for any reason there is a delay between keyavailable and readkey then does that mean there is a possibility that I will miss that key?

Comment: Why would the input buffer be flushed to the console? It doesn't discard keypresses (unless you overflow the buffer). They will be available as soon as the application asks for them. To test this out, https://dotnetfiddle.net/QzjVod (you have to copy it to a local app, won't run in Fiddle)

Comment: So the keyboard input is being stored in a buffer as soon as the console launches? Readkey just reads what is in this buffer in the order it was input?

Comment: Yes, unless you overflow the OS keyboard buffer, at which point either the OS will stop accepting keys (you'll hear the "DING"), or will discard the older key presses, I don't remember exactly which happens but you can test it.

Comment: *System designers who do not allow users to type far ahead ought to be tarred and feathered, or worse yet, be forced to use their own system.* [Operating Systems Design and Implementation, Andrew S. Tanenbaum](https://it421.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/operatingsystemsdesignandimple.pdf)

Comment: `ReadKey()` is blocking anyway. You don't need `if(Console.KeyAvailable)` here. It works the same without it (unless there's other code in the loop that you want to run while waiting for a key).

Comment: Rufus If(Console.KeyAvailable) ensures that it doesnt block unless a key was pressed. Without it application will just hang on Console.ReadKey for every iteration

Comment: @cubesnyc Yeah, that's what I'm saying, though. In this example, it's the same.

Comment: Baffled why anyone would vote to close this as unclear...